# Password is not supplied for ssh login

Tags: ssh, expect

I'm trying to login to a remote host using expect & spawn. While automating this it's going till `ssh username@host.example.com` and password prompt came and it is terminating wihtout supplying the password. What is wrong with this script ?

`#!/usr/bin/expect`
`set timeout 9`
`passwrd=PASSWORD`
`username=USER_NAME`
`host=host.example.com`

`/usr/bin/expect << EOF`

`spawn ssh $username@$host`
`expect "Password:"`
`send "$passwrd\r"`
`interact`

Comment: Is the last line meant to be `ineract`? Looks like it should say `interact` (complete guess here). Is it a typo in your question or in your actual code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're confusing expect syntax and shell syntax. You want:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 9
set passwrd PASSWORD
set username USER_NAME
set host host.example.com

spawn ssh $username@$host
expect "Password:"
send "$passwrd\r"
interact
```